# How to use the istanbul API to load config from grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, istanbul

I am trying to steer istanbul from grunt without resorting to a `.istanbul.yml` file. The idea is to run [grunt-jasmine-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jasmine-nodejs) for unit testing and integrate istanbul as a custom reporter:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine_nodejs: {
      options: {
        specNameSuffix: 'spec.js',
        useHelpers: false,
        reporters: {
          console: {}
        },
        customReporters: [
          require('./tests/lib/istanbul-reporter.js')({
            coverageVar: '__coverage__',
            dir: './tests/coverage'
            reports: ['text','json','html']
          })
        ]
      },
      default: {
        specs: [ 'tests/unit/**' ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-nodejs');
};
```

The jasmine reporter also notifies [sandboxed-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandboxed-module) that it should instrument the tested files. The [istanbul API doc](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/apidocs/classes/Config.html#method_loadFile) gives the idea that it loads configuration with `.loadFile()`:

```
module.exports = function (opt) {
    var istanbul = require('istanbul');
    istanbul.config.loadFile(false, {
        instrumentation: { variable: opt.coverageVar },
        reporting: { dir: opt.dir }
    });        

    var SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module');
    SandboxedModule.registerBuiltInSourceTransformer('istanbul');
    global[opt.coverageVar] = {};

    var collector, reporter;

    return {
        jasmineStarted: function () {
            collector = new istanbul.Collector();
            reporter = new istanbul.Reporter();
            reporter.addAll(opt.reports);
        },
        suiteStarted: function () {},
        suiteDone: function () {},
        specStarted: function () {},
        specDone: function () {},
        jasmineDone: function () {
            console.log('\n\n');
            collector.add(global[opt.coverageVar]);
            reporter.write(collector, true, function () {
                return;
            });
        }
    };
};
```

It doesn't work. I've tried several variants, including `config.loadObject(config.defaultConfig(), {...})`, but the overrides are not applied.

Apart from writing a `.istanbul.yml` file from the grunt config data, is there a programatic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`istanbul.config.loadFile` does not initialize anything, it gives back an object for further usage.

In addition, sandboxed-module currently does not take options for the instrumenter it uses. There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module/pull/58) to handle this.

So for the time being, a custom source transformer is needed. My rewritten custom jasmine reporter now looks like this:

```
var istanbul = require('istanbul');
var instrumentMethod;

exports.init = function (opt) {
    var collector, reporter;

    global[opt.instrumenting.coverageVariable] = {};

    return {
        jasmineStarted: function () {
            var configObj = istanbul.config.loadFile(false, opt);        
            var instrumenter = new istanbul.Instrumenter(opt.instrumenting);
            instrumentMethod = instrumenter.instrumentSync.bind(instrumenter);
            collector = new istanbul.Collector();
            reporter = new istanbul.Reporter(configObj);
            reporter.addAll(opt.reporting.reports);
        },
        suiteStarted: function () {},
        suiteDone: function () {},
        specStarted: function () {},
        specDone: function () {},
        jasmineDone: function () {
            console.log('\n\n');
            collector.add(global[opt.instrumenting.coverageVariable]);
            reporter.write(collector, true, function () {
                return;
            });
        }
    };
};

exports.transformer =  function (source) {
    source = instrumentMethod(source, this.filename);
    return source;
};
```

The `opt` parameter is not compatible to the YAML file. There are two reasons:

1. Large parts deal with handling multiple files, while the setup with sandboxed-module is dealing with single files: you get the file, you transform it.
2. `hooks` and `checks` are handled outside defining instrumenters, collectors and reporters.

To avoid confusion, I've named the first part `instrumenting`, not `instrumentation`. It is handed to `new Instrumenter(opt.instrumenting)`. Note that the [documentation](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/apidocs/classes/Instrumenter.html) is outdated (v0.3.0). The second part `reporting` is fully compatible to its counterpart in the YAML.

In the Gruntfile, noting the defaults:

```
require('./tests/lib/istanbul-reporter.js').init({
    instrumenting: {
        debug: false,                       // not in YAML
        walkDebug: false,                   // not in YAML
        codeGenerationOptions: undefined,   // not in YAML, see escodegen
        noAutoWrap: false,                  // not in YAML
        coverageVariable: '__coverage__',   // YAML name is variable
        noCompact: false,                   // YAML states compact: true
        embedSource: false,
        preserveComments: false,
        esModules: false
    },
    reporting: {
                                            // same as YAML
    }
}
```

And finally, in the jasmine spec:

```
var SandboxedModule = require('sandboxed-module');
var isr = require('../lib/istanbul-reporter.js');

var testedModule = SandboxedModule.require('../../lib/tested-module.js', {
    // requires: { },
    // globals: { }, ...
    sourceTransformers: {
        istanbul: isr.transformer
    }
});
```